# Handling ajax request response with wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, request

i've done an ajax request in my wordpress plugin.My request is based on steps below:

**1) i am including js file and starting a request document on ready**

**2)At the php side i want to take this request and print it to test.**

for all these stuff i wrote these codes:

main.js:

```
 $(function(){      
    $.post('/wp-content/plugins/dsn/functions.php',{token:"1tibu4"},function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },"json");
 });
```

functions.php:

```
 <?php 

   add_action('loop_end', 'init');

   function init(){
       global $_POST;

       $post= $_POST;   
       echo json_encode($post);Exit;

   }
```

My question is when request complete there is nothing on the response tab of console screen.How come this happen?

Comment: Do you have a question? Are you saying the code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: sorry i have edited my question

Comment: Check your PHP error log, are there any errors?

Comment: What does the console say the response code is? 200, 500, 404?

Comment: http://oi46.tinypic.com/9lh6s9.jpg it's screen shot of response.I guess it's succesfully returns 200.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress has a unique way of handling AJAX. If you make a request to the php file directly, then you are not loading the rest of the WordPress framework and a lot of WordPress specific functionality will not be available to you.

In the PHP side, what you have to do is use code that looks like this:

```
//for logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
//for not logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
  //your function here
  exit; //always call exit at the end of a WordPress ajax function
}
```

In the JS side, you need to send your request to a file called "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

So your request would look like this (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type : 'get', //or 'post'
    data : {
                action: 'my_action_callback'
            }
})
     .fail(function(r,status,jqXHR) {
         console.log('failed');
     });
     .done(function(r,status,jqXHR) {
        console.log('success');
     });
```

Note the my_action_callback parts.

Comment: i thank you for reply,i tried your way,but when the page loads no ajax request being sent

Comment: If no ajax request is being sent, it's because you're not sending it. That really doesn't have anything to do with the answer that I have provided.

Comment: I don't think the code above is correct, but the idea is dead-on, thanks Adam.  Please refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins for the current instructions.

Comment: please change this is not working now.
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enqueued your custom script as follows. If your script is included before the Wordpress jQuery scripts are custom injected your code might not work properly.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```